# Images don't appear when setting canvas size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a for loop that dynamically creates `span` or `img` elements depending on what's in a `div` then I put it on the canvas. The width of the canvas should be equal to the combined widths of all the images and text.  Everything goes fine until I change the width of the canvas using `canvas.width = prevX.`  When I use this the canvas outputs nothing.  When I use `console.log(canvas.width)` it shows that the canvas width is growing, but the images are not printing.  How do I dynamically change the canvas width?

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas")
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
        let imgDiv = document.querySelector(".images")
        let imgEl = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
        let spanEl = document.getElementsByTagName("span")
        let divEl = imgDiv.hasChildNodes()
        let prevX = 0
        if (divEl){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
            canvas.height = 34
            for(var n=0; n<imgDiv.children.length; n++){
                if (imgDiv.children[n].nodeName === "IMG"){
                    ctx.drawImage(imgDiv.children[n], prevX ,0);
                }
                else if(imgDiv.children[n].nodeName === "SPAN"){
                    ctx.font = window.getComputedStyle(spanEl[0]).fontSize + " Open Sans"
                    ctx.fillText(imgDiv.children[n].innerHTML, prevX ,parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(spanEl[0]).fontSize,10))
                }
                prevX += imgDiv.children[n].width
                canvas.width = prevX
            }
        }
```

EDIT:  Changed code to use `getImageData()` and `putImageData()`.  The width and height changes, but the the images do not show.  I might be inserting `putImageData()` in the wrong place.

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas")
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
        let imgDiv = document.querySelector(".images")
        let imgEl = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
        let spanEl = document.getElementsByTagName("span")
        let divEl = imgDiv.hasChildNodes()
        let prevX = 0
        canvas.height = 34
        canvas.width = 32
        var imagedata = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
        ctx.putImageData(imagedata,0,0)
        if (divEl){
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
            for(var n=0; n<imgDiv.children.length; n++){
                if (imgDiv.children[n].nodeName === "IMG"){
                    ctx.drawImage(imgDiv.children[n], prevX ,0)
                    prevX += imgDiv.children[n].width
                }
                else if(imgDiv.children[n].nodeName === "SPAN"){
                    ctx.font = window.getComputedStyle(spanEl[0]).fontSize + " Open Sans"
                    ctx.fillText(imgDiv.children[n].innerHTML, prevX ,parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(spanEl[0]).fontSize,10))
                    prevX += imgDiv.children[n].width
                }
                canvas.width = prevX
            }
        }
        console.log(canvas.width)
        console.log(canvas.height)
        console.log(imagedata)
```

Comment: What does that `canvas.height` inside else if do?

Comment: That shouldn't have been there.  I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the height of width attribute via `canvas.width = 500` (for instance), it actually clears the content of the canvas (at least in Chrome), *then* makes it bigger, effectively emptying it. 
What you could do then is store the image data before resizing with `getImageData()`, then resize, then use `putImageData()` to redraw your stuff if the new, bigger canvas.

Example of a code that works and adds (cat) pictures one after the other while resizing the canvas appropriately:

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="source" src="cat.png"
       width="260" height="270"> 
</div>
<button>Click to duplicate</button>
```

**JS**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image = document.getElementById('source');
canvas.width = 260; //native image size is 260 * 270
canvas.height = 270;

ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 260, 270);

var numberOfCats = 1;
$("button").on('click', () =>{
    currentData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    canvas.height = (numberOfCats + 1) * 270 ;
    ctx.putImageData(currentData, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, numberOfCats * 270, 260, 270);
    numberOfCats += 1;
})
```

**EDIT: additional details regarding the use of `getImageData()`**

Now that I think about it: `getImageData()` is a handy yet sometimes annoying to use feature, as it can easily trigger a cross origin error, namely the `The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.` error.

> **What is a tainted canvas?**
>
> Although you can use images without CORS
>   approval in your canvas, doing so taints the canvas. Once a canvas has
>   been tainted, you can no longer pull data back out of the canvas. For
>   example, **you can no longer use the canvas toBlob(), toDataURL(), or
>   getImageData() methods; doing so will throw a security error.**
>
> This protects users from having private data exposed by using images
>   to pull information from remote web sites without permission.
>   ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image), emphasis by me)

This will occur everytime your image source is coming from a different origin than the one emitting your HTML string (note that this include the cases where you work locally and try to include a picture from the same folder!). A few ways to work around this:

- set up a small local web server (example for node js: run `npm
  install http-server -g` then `http-server . -p 9600` will start a
  server on localhost:9600)
- if you have access to the remote server hosting the picture, you can 
  set its `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `"*"`
- you can disable security parameters (**this is not recommended**)

More details available [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/How-to-run-thing-locally)

Comment: Thank you for this.  I've tried following your examples, but it is still not showing the images.  It is outputting the correct width and height though.  I've edited my post.

Comment: Nevermind I got it working.  It's the order in which I did things that was wrong.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: My pleasure ! I'm currently battling with canvas as well, so I feel you ...